# Querying a table in SQL Server based on permutation of column2 and 3

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
col1    col2    col3
111     1       1
222     1       0
333     0       1
444     0       0
```

Here `col2 = 1` means `col1` is commercial, `col3 = 1` means `col1` is retail as well. How do I get a result like below?

```
ID      Description 
111     Commercial  
111     Retail
222     Commercial  
333     Retail
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with a `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ID = col1, 'Commercial' FROM MyTable WHERE col2=1
    UNION ALL
SELECT ID = col1, 'Retail' FROM MyTable WHERE col3=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Uses almost the same as above but in a single result set

```
Select ID = col1, t.Description
from MyTable
cross apply (select Description = 'Commercial' where col2 = 1   union 
             select Description = 'Retail' where coll3 = 1)t
```

Comment: If you want to reference another answer, it's usually better to link to it (there's a share link below each answer which will give you a URL, and I'd usually use a phrase like "dasblinkenlight's answer" as the link text) rather than to use "positional" language like "above" - after all, the position of answers can change based on voting and acceptance.

Comment: dasblinkenlight's answer also only has a single resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with `UNPIVOT` also:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      col1 INT ,
      col2 INT ,
      col3 INT
    )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 111, 1, 1 ),
        ( 222, 1, 0 ),
        ( 333, 0, 1 ),
        ( 444, 0, 0 )

SELECT  col1 ,
        CASE WHEN col = 'col2' THEN 'Commercial'
             ELSE 'Retail'
        END AS Description
FROM    @t UNPIVOT( r FOR col IN ( [col2], [col3] ) ) u
WHERE   r <> 0
```